# Deseo descargar con javascript un pdf desde una url, seguidamente enviar por post a un sitio que lo reciba con php y lo almacene en el servidor

Tags: php, ajax

éste código de javascript se encuentra en un servidor y el código de php se encuentra en otro servidor. el pdf que se desea almacenar pertenece a un tercer servidor.

```
<script>
// hace la petición y envía sin problemas
$.ajax({ 
     url: 'www.example.com/archivo.pdf', type: 'get', 
     success: function(data_pdf) {
        $.ajax({ 
          url: 'www.miservidor.com/guardar.php', 
          type: 'post', 
          data: { archivo : data_pdf }, 
          success: function(data_res){  
             console.log(data_res);  
        }});
}});
<script>

<?php
// recibe el post y almacena sin problemas
$filename = 'miarchivo.pdf'
$content = $_POST['archivo'];
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
// al abrir el archivo sale vacío
?>
```

Comment: si dentro del success pones `console.log(data_pdf);` que te sale en consola?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: necesitas crear un form data al vuelo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708214/17161735